# Greeting for a newborn baby?

Tags: expressions

How can I start my Japanese greeting card for a newborn?

Is the following a correct sentence, in Japanese?

> 新しい両親になるからおめでとうございます

Answer (score 5):

The most common, therefore the safest, first phrases would include:

> 「ご出産{しゅっさん}おめでとう（ございます）！」
>
> 「赤{あか}ちゃんの（ご）誕生{たんじょう}おめでとう！」
>
> 「お子様{こさま}のご誕生、心{こころ}よりお祝{いわ}い申{もう}し上{あ}げます。」
>
> 「[Baby name]ちゃんのご誕生おめでとう！」 ← if you already know the baby's name.

Your attempt does not sound quite right unfortunately.  「なるから」 is too colloquial/conversational.  You could perhaps choose one from the above and add a line like:

> 「これで〇〇さんと〇〇さんもパパとママになれたね！」　← if the baby is the couple's first child.

NOTE: Greetings in Japanese are not very simple.  What phrases would be best for you would depend on the relationship between you and the baby's parents.  Without that piece of information, I could only give you the very common ones.

Finally, if I were the parents of the newborn, I would be ***much*** happier to receive a message with two dozen mistakes than a perfect one written with the help of an internet native speaker.  The baby's parents know exactly what your current Japanese proficiency is like, don't they?  Trust me, they would not expect more than what you could come up with on your own.

This is something I have been telling Japanese-learners for many years without much success, unfortunately.